# Один бэкенд на множество доменов

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, domain, lumen

Прошу подсказать как правильно организовать архитектуру приложения:

Сейчас есть:

1. админ панель - фронт+бэк на laravel
2. клиентская часть - фронт+бэк на [lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/)

3. Общая БД для п1-2

В админ панели привязываются множество доменов для клиентской части (site1.ru,site2.ru), когда клиент заходит на site1.ru бэк клиентской части должен выдавать один контент из БД, когда заходит на site2.ru бэк выдаёт другое содержимое из БД.

Вопрос: как,архитектурно, выдавать контент в зависимости от домена ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [multi-tenancy](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Ваша зачада на хостинг сделать чтобы запросы с обоих доменов проходили через ваше приложение и дальше уже в роутах определять с какого домена запросы:

```
Route::domain('site1.ru')->group(function () {
    //роуты для 'site1.ru'
});
Route::domain('site2.ru')->group(function () {
    //роуты для 'site1.ru'
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: а если таких доменов ооочень много ? Моё приложение - это что-то вроде генератора сайтов Wix.com, когда пользователь регистрируется, он может указать свой домен и моё приложение должно обрабатывать Route::domain('домен пользователя')